# Python: how to set up a requests.post

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to programmatically use this tool http://www.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer so that I can batch analyze a few dozen DNA sequences.

Peeking inside Chrome's developer tools, I see that I am sending a POST request when I click the Analyze button (after entering a sequence (eg "AACCGGTT") in the Sequence field). In the Response tab, I can also see the response (eg "MeltTemp") that I wish to collect. So, following the tutorial (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request), I put together the snippet below, but it's clearly not working.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer/home/analyze'  # from: ChromeDevTools -> Network -> Name: analyze -> tab: Headers -> General -> Request URL
>>> data = {"settings":{"Sequence":"AACCGGTT",  # from: ChromeDevTools -> Network -> Name: analyze -> tab: Headers -> Request Payload
                        "NaConc":50,
                        "MgConc":0,
                        "DNTPsConc":0,
                        "OligoConc":0.25,
                        "NucleotideType":"DNA",
                       }}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=data)

>>> r.url  # 404 page
u'http://www.idtdna.com/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/calc/analyzer/home/analyze'

# I was hoping for something like this that gives me the JSON response (which can be found at
# ChromeDevTools -> Network -> Name: analyze -> tab: Response)
>>> r.some_magical_function()
{"Sequence":"AAC CGG TTG GTT AAT T","NaConc":50,  ... "MeltTemp":45.1, ...}
```

What am I missing?

Does the post request need to be way more complicated (with cookies? session??)? If so, please provide pointers to what I need to learn (or the solution :p)

I understand if the website has safeguards against this kind of usage; if it's basically impossible, then what strategy do you suggest?selenium?

Comment: http://www.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer/home/analyze does not exist, it returns `404 Not Found`. Why do you think this is the URL to `POST` to?

Comment: It seems that the web site makes the POST request to http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer/home/analyze instead

Comment: I am voting to close this question, because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: As commented below, I thought it was `www` (instead of the `sg`, as pointed out by niemmi) based on the request: ChromeDevTools -> Network -> Name: analyze -> tab: Headers -> General -> Request URL. Perhaps this is not where I should get the POST address...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As niemmi commented, the actual url is http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer/home/analyze
- The site require cookies set (You need to access the page at least once before actual request using [`request.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to set cookie)
- You need to pass json-encoded data (you can use `json=...` argument)

---

```
import requests

url = 'http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer/home/analyze'
data = {
    'settings': {
        'Sequence': 'AACCGGTT',
        'NaConc': 50,
        'MgConc': 0,
        'DNTPsConc': 0,
        'OligoConc': 0.25,
        'NucleotideType': 'DNA',
    }
}

s = requests.Session()
s.get('http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer')  # to set cookies
r = s.post(url, json=data)
print(r.json())
```

---

**UPDATE**

Depending on location, redirection does not happen. In such case use `www.idtdna.com` instead of `sg.idtdna.com`.

Comment: Could you tell me where/how to find the correct url? I thought it was `www` (instead of the `sg`) based on the request: ChromeDevTools -> Network -> Name: analyze -> tab: Headers  -> General -> Request URL. I can't seem to find anywhere the `sg` address...

Comment: Also, @falsetru, is this solution tested? I get: `print(r.json())` `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` and `r.url` is the 404 page I mentioned in the question....

Comment: @obk, When I visit http://www.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer, it is redirected to http://sg.idtdna.com/calc/analyzer . http://i.imgur.com/igbyUKA.png

Comment: thx for the demo, appreciate it. but now I'm confused... because I don't get redirected. see: https://i.imgur.com/YNsJLXF.jpg  How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: @obk, What do you get if you replace all occurences of `sg` with `www` in the anser code, and run it?

Comment: It works! Can you edit your answer to mention that the address may be `www` (depending on where in the world you access from?) and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @obk, I updated the answer to address that. Thank you for the feedback.